# Google Maps and accessing returned Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, https, require

This will almost certainly be something super basic but I cannot for the life of me work out what's wrong. I have a data object coming back from Google Maps JS API

```
    {
   "destination_addresses" : [ "12 Ansell Rd, London SW17, UK" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [
      "911 Alfreds Way, Barking IG11 0AX, UK",
      "911 Alfreds Way, Barking IG11 0AX, UK",
      "50 Buttesland St, Hoxton, London N1 6BY, UK"
   ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "24.4 km",
                  "value" : 24411
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "55 mins",
                  "value" : 3297
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "58 mins",
                  "value" : 3454
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "24.4 km",
                  "value" : 24411
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "55 mins",
                  "value" : 3297
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "58 mins",
                  "value" : 3454
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "13.9 km",
                  "value" : 13905
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "48 mins",
                  "value" : 2909
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "45 mins",
                  "value" : 2717
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I'm retrieving this using .get with require's https module and it works absolutely fine and then I print the data like so...

```
https.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=51.5285,0.0847|51.5285,0.0847|51.5285,-0.0847&destinations=51.432622,-0.164496&departure_time=now&key=APIKEY`, (resp) => {

      let data = '';
        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });
        //When all data is received
        resp.on('end', () => {
            console.log(data);
        });

    });
```

The problem is as soon as I try to access (even just console log) any data in the object like

`data.destination_addresses`

it returns undefined. I thought this might be to do with asynchronous issues but it doesn't make sense that I can print the data variable but not it's attributes individually

Comment: As it's written here, there is no problem printing `console.log(data.destination_addresses)`. It works fine with the data you've shown. Are you trying to access it outside the `on` `end` handler? Is there more data (for instance is it an array of these objects)?

Comment: Can you please provide an actual code sample, but with passwords/api keys scrubbed?  The only problem I see with the above code, is that data isn't defined as a parameter in the resp listener.

Comment: @MarkMeyer no sir

Comment: @Daedalus added, thank you for investigating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need parse it as JSON first

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(obj.destination_addresses);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help sir! Just to avoid me making this mistake again - what was happening? Why did it need parsing? Was what Google returning not JSON?

Comment: It was returning JSON as a STRING which you would need to parse as JSON using the code above so you can access the object.  See more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse